# Why is state not showing up in the Modalize onOpened event?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-modalize

I have what seems to be a simple setup.

- Some state the that holds the selected task.
- A `useEffect` that
  opens the modal when the state is updated.

The modal opens, and inside the `TaskScreen` I'm able to console log `selectedTask`.

The problem is the `onOpened` prop never has the `selectedTask`. It always logs `undefined`.

How can `TaskScreen` have the correct value but not the `onOpened` prop? They're both rendered at the same time.

```js
const taskModalRef = useRef(undefined);
const [selectedTask, setSelectedTask] = useState(undefined);

useEffect(() => {
  if (selectedTask) {
    taskModalRef.current.open();
  }
})

<Modalize
  ref={taskModalRef}
  onOpened={() => {
    console.log('selectedTask', selectedTask); //  always undefined.
  }}
>
  <TaskScreen task={selectedTask} /> //  always has the correct value.
</Modalize>
```

Comment: just try const [selectedTask, setSelectedTask] = useState(null) to see if it logs null

Comment: Hey. Thanks for the response but I'm not exactly sure what you're saying... of course it logs null in that case. It logs whatever I put as the default value. The problem is I want it to have the new value. I have a button that calls `setSelectedTask` which then triggers the useEffect and opens the modal passing in the selectedTask. I was thinking it was memoized but looking at the Modalize source it doesn't seem to be.

Comment: I guess onOpened run before selectedTask is set

Comment: But then it would be undefined in both cases.

Comment: Could it be that react memoize the value of `onOpened ` and re-run the same function everytime. While in `task={selectedTask}` the value is updated for every render.

Comment: I guess you would need an additional `useEffect(() => {setSelectedTask(selectedTask)}, [selectedTask])` to update the internal state of your component to recreate the value of `onOpened` on state change.

Comment: I bookmarked this question originally but I guess you only see the obvious 6 months later.